# Razor views - @if statement compilation error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Razor views scaffolded by Visual Studio contains an "actions" element with links separated by pipe character (`|`)

```
<td>
   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
   @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
</td>
```

I would like to render those links conditionally:

```
<td>
    @if (item.IsSuccess)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    }
</td>
```

The code above seems correct in Visual Studio, however execution results in an `Compilation Error`

> ```
> Compilation Error
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required    
> to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and
> modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1513: Expected sign }.
>
> Source Error:
>
>
> Line 491:        }
> Line 492:    }
> Line 493:}
> ```

Can you please point me where is the problem? The code seems syntactially correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you break into a c# block, you must explicitly break out again. You can use the `<text>` tag to add one or more lines of literal text to the output in this case.

```
<td>
    @if (item.IsSuccess)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })<text> |</text>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })<text> |</text>
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    }
</td>
```

Or as John H mentioned, you can use the syntax `@:` to break out of the code block for single lines of text.

```
<td>
    @if (item.IsSuccess)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })@: |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })@: |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
    }
</td>
```

See also [Combining Text, Markup, and Code in Code Blocks](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)#BM_CombiningTextMarkupAndCode)

Comment: You're right, but there's a simpler way.  `<text> |</text>` can be changed to: `@:|`, and it will have the same effect.

Comment: @JohnH - Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks! Can you please provide me a link to documentation describing how it works and why `<text>` or `@:` expressions are needed? Seems slighlty ugly but apparently thats the way to go..

Comment: I added a link to my answer.